# Ubuntu 18.04 Connected to Wi-Fi but no internet?

Tags: wireless, internet

I just installed Ubuntu on my laptop and I've been having some issues connecting to the internet. When I login to my account, the UI tells me I am connected to my Wi-Fi network, however when I open Firefox and try to go to Google, I get a message telling me I am not connected to the internet.

Lots of solutions on here tell people to type `sudo service network-manager restart` into the terminal, but that doesn't work at all for me. In fact once I type that, the computer cannot see any Wi-Fi networks at all until I reboot.

I made sure that my Wi-Fi password is correct, and I have tried rebooting several times. Any help would be amazing.

Thanks!

Comment: What does the terminal command `ip route` show? Is there a `default` route?

Comment: ip route shows nothing at all

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue  that I can connect to the router but can't connect to other sites (when Im connected to wifi) and it keep saying resolving host and if I switched to the wired connection, internet worked correctly

to fix it I tried many answers, finally, I did the following

go to

`sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`

the file should look like this

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

## comment out these things if you have them 
#allow-hotplug eno1
#iface eno1 inet dhcp
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Network Manager logs with `journalctl $(type -p NetworkManager)`.

Use `/sbin/ifconfig` to find the name of your WiFi interface (I'll use `wlan0` in the following example, replace `wlan0` with your interface name). Use `/usr/sbin/arp -an` to find the IP address of your router. (I'll use 11.22.33.44 in the example)

```
sudo ip route add default via 11.22.33.44 dev wlan0
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I dont have access to ifconfig or arp. When I type that into the terminal it says I neee to sudo-apt-install them but I can't do that because I don't have an internet connection

Comment: You do have these commands, just not in your `PATH`. I've added full paths to my answer.